# NodeJS / Problem when migrating from windows to redhat

Tags: node.js

I have moved a project from windows to a linux server.
When I try to

```
run node app.js
```

> Require stack:
>
> - /var/www/html/FRANSUA/GEECCDMP/routes/index.js
> - /var/www/html/FRANSUA/GEECCDMP/app.js

> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND

I don't get why it is running on windows and not on linux.

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.set('views', './views'); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Express server listening on port 3000`));

module.exports = app;
```

I have checked if this could be relative to the end on line sequence, but no luck.

Thanks for your feedback

**EDIT A**

I have renammed my node_modules to node_mudles_old and have tried to execute a basic

```
npm install express
```

It blocks to

> idealTree:rijs.sync: sill fetch manifest xtend@^4.0.0

**EDIT B**

I have tried to run as non root user with

```
npm install express --verbose
```

Blocking at :

```
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 12ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
```

Comment: Asking the obvious first: What is `run node app.js` or did you mean when you "run `node app.js`"? Did you run this in the correct directory (ie where `app.js` is located). Does `./routes/index.js` exist relative to that directory? Does the user executing this command have all the necessary permissions to access all files and directories?

Comment: I have run with root privilege `node app.js` and yes there is a ./routes/index.js

Comment: A sorry, my bad, if `./routes/index` is part of the require stack, it is already found ... So it's actually some `require` within that file (if it's the topmost in the require stack) that isn't found. The error message should also tell you its name.

Comment: Did you use `npm install` (or yarn or whatever) to fetch the dependencies? You must do so. Just copying node_modules does not work. Does your error message say anything else? Please [edit] your question to tell us more about your situation. And avoid root. Running nodejs apps as root can drop files in weird places that prevent running it as non-root but are obscure.